# Binding Class in MVVM Light to RelayCommand in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm-light

I am trying to bind the following class to a relaycommand.

```
  public class UserAuth
  {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
  }
```

This is my MainActivity Class:

```
public partial class MainActivity : ActivityBaseEx
{

     private Binding<string, UserAuth> _userInformation;


    private Binding<string, UserAuth> _cool;

    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return App.Locator.Login;
        }
    }


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);



         _userInformation = this.SetBinding(()=> **....... WHAT GOES HERE!! I can do this for a simple string, but cannot figure it out for a class!**


        // Get our button from the layout resource and attach an event to it
        var signInButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSingIn);

        signInButton.SetCommand("Click", LoginViewModel.LoginCommand, _userInformation);

    }
```

}

This is my RelayCommand in my View Model

```
  public RelayCommand<UserAuth> LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new RelayCommand<UserAuth>(
                async (userAuth) =>
                {

                    _isLoading = true;

                    try
                    {
                        //   var loggedIn = await _loginService.AuthenticateUser("emediaqa1", "p098765");

                        var loggedIn = await _loginService.AuthenticateUser(userAuth.UserName, userAuth.Password);

                        _isLoading = false;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        var dialog = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IDialogService>();
                        dialog.ShowError(ex, "Error  Authenticating", "OK", null);
                    }

                    _isLoading = false;
                }));
        }
    }
```

My problem is with this line:

```
_userInformation = this.SetBinding(()=> // WHAT GOES HERE!! I can do  this for a simple 
                                        //string, but  cannot figure it out for a class!
```

Please help!

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?>

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this in the MainActivity.OnCreate:

```
_usernameBinding = this.SetBinding(() => Vm.userAuth.Username, () => Username.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
 _passwordBinding = this.SetBinding(() => Vm.userAuth.Password, () => Password.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

So you need 2 bindings, one for userName and one for Password.